# Ignore methods/void methods using EasyMock with Junit

Tags: java, junit, junit4, easymock

*"Added more details"*

I want to Mock a certain void method but i'm not quite sure how to. I read about EasyMock but i don't know what to do when it's a void method, This is my main class;

**Main class**

```
public class Main {
    Updater updater = new Updater(main.getID(), main.getName(),....);

    try {
        updater.updateContent(dir);
    }
```

i want to mock `updater.updateContent(dir);`  so that i can skip the **try**

**Updater class**

```
private String outD;

public void updateContent(final String outDir) throws Exception {


    outD = outDir;
    if (...) {
        ....;
    }

}
```

`...` private void methods

This is my test class so far,

```
public class MainTest {


    @Before
    public void setUp() {

    }

    @Test
    public void testMain() { 


try {


        try {
            Updater updater = EasyMock.createNiceMock(Updater.class);
            updater.updateContent("/out");
            EasyMock.expectLastCall().andThrow(new RuntimeException()); 

            EasyMock.replay(updater);

            updater.updateContent("/out");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 


    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


}
    }
```

(edited) thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by "skip the try" ?

Comment: @dkatzel meaning i don't want to execute `updater.updateContent(dir);`

Answer (score 1):

For methods returning void you must record the behavior this way:

```
 Updater updater = EasyMock.createNiceMock(Updater.class);
 updater.updateContent("someDir"); // invoke the easy mock proxy and
 // after invoking it record the behaviour.
 EasyMock.expectLastCall().andThrow(new RuntimeException()); // for example

 EasyMock.replay(updater);

 updater.updateContent("someDir"); // will throw the RuntimeException as recorded
```

Expect you have the following `Main` class

```
public class Main {
    private Updater updater;

    private int updatedContentCount; // introduced for the example

    public Main(Updater updater) {
        this.updater = updater;
    }

    public void updateContent() {
        try {
            updater.updateContent("/out");
            updatedContentCount++;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // skip for this example - normally you should handle this
        }
    }

    public int getUpdatedContentCount() {
        return updatedContentCount;
    }

}
```

and your updater's API looks like this

```
public class Updater {

    public void updateContent(String dir) throws Exception {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Then a test of the `Main` class would be something like this:

```
public class MainTest {

    private Updater updater;
    private Main main;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        updater = EasyMock.createNiceMock(Updater.class);
        main = new Main(updater);
    }

    @Test
    public void testUpdateCountOnException() throws Exception {
        updater.updateContent("/out");
        EasyMock.expectLastCall().andThrow(new RuntimeException());
        EasyMock.replay(updater);
        main.updateContent();
        int updatedContentCount = main.getUpdatedContentCount();
        Assert.assertEquals(
                "Updated count must not have been increased on exception", 0,
                updatedContentCount);
    }
}
```

The `MainTest` tests if the updateCount is handled correctly on an exception of the `Updater`.

Comment: i added what you have given please take a look and see whats wrong

Comment: At the moment I can't figure out how your classes really work. Nevertheless I will update my answer and show you how a test could work.

Comment: when i run it with junit it still goes to the `updateContent` method

Comment: The code I added is an assumption of what I think you want to do, because the code you provided is not enough. Thus I added the code to show the basic principles of a unit test.

Comment: ya im going to try it now.. i also updated main class take a look at it too :)

Comment: Ok, but when you want to mock a class you have to replace the reference. With your current design it is not possible, because the Updater gets instantiated in the main method.

Comment: Could you please post the complete source code of Updater, Main and MainTest?